# CAEmitterLayer animation not working on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I have developed an app using CAEmitterLayer. Initially I made it to emit automatically (when the app loads, it will start emitting the sparkles), it worked fine both in simulator and device.

Now, I changed it to emit when user taps on the screen. It works fine in simulator. On device, its not reacting. Please assist me in the right direction.

Initialized tap in `-viewDidLoad`

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
```

Assigned in `-viewWillAppear`

```
tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (void) particles {

    if (!sparkling) {

        rootLayer = [CALayer layer];
        rootLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        CGColorRef color = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        rootLayer.backgroundColor = color;
        CGColorRelease(color);

        const char* fileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DazStarOutline" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String];
        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(fileName);
        id img = (__bridge id)CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

        const char* fileNameR = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DazRing" ofType:@"png"] UTF8String];
        CGDataProviderRef dataProviderR = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(fileNameR);
        id imgR = (__bridge id)CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProviderR, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

        mortor = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
        mortor.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(320, 0);
        mortor.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerAdditive;

        CAEmitterCell *rocket = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
        rocket.emissionLongitude = M_PI / 2;
        rocket.emissionLatitude = 0;
        rocket.lifetime = 2.0;
        rocket.birthRate = 1;
        rocket.velocity = 400;
        rocket.velocityRange = 100;
        rocket.yAcceleration = -250;
        rocket.emissionRange = M_PI / 4;
        color = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.5] CGColor];
        rocket.color = color;
        CGColorRelease(color);
        rocket.redRange = 0.5;
        rocket.greenRange = 0.5;
        rocket.blueRange = 0.5;

        CAEmitterCell *spark = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
        spark.contents = img;
        spark.lifetime = 0.05;
        spark.yAcceleration = -250;
        spark.beginTime = 0.8;
        spark.scale = 0.4;
        spark.birthRate = 10;

        preSpark.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:spark, nil];
        rocket.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flare, nil];
        mortor.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rocket, nil];
        [rootLayer addSublayer:mortor];
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:rootLayer];

        sparkling = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Tap Gesture Method

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    [self particles];
}
```

Comment: If you will spend 15 minutes and create a demo project with just a single view and this emitter (and images), and post it to your public DropBox folder, I'd love to take a look at it. Its probably something simple and just doing the demo app may let you find it. The demo app is just a single view app, add the tap recognizer to the primary view, so its real real simple.

Comment: Would do it for sure... I’ll post the link here :-) @David

Comment: @DavidH Please get it from here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97646145/SampleEmission.zip I’d like to get a reply from u asap =)

Comment: I downloaded the project and tried to run it in the Simulator - it crashed when I tapped on the screen (maybe earlier). I ran 'Analyze' under the Product menu - something you should do - and it gave me several errors (like, you use __bridge but are not using ARC). Fix those errors, get the app to at least run in Simulator and Device, then I can retest. Is this suppose to be ARC? If so why is one or more files not ARC? I will not be able to look at this again until tonight NYC,NY time.

Comment: I am sorry sir. It works fine at my end. I uploaded the code only after testing it. It gives me only one error (memory leakage at CGColorRelease(color);) while analyzing. Its not an ARC supported project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I downloaded your project. Two issues - one is that the CFRelease is not proper - you don't own that color. But more important, if you take a color from a UIColor CGColor, you should really use the CG method to copy the color, then manage that resource. I know this gets complex, but when you mix CG and UI you will get complexity - you cannot avoid it.

I took your project, converted to ARC, then also created strong ivars that hold the UIColors that you want to use (as CGColorRefs). You cannot create a tempt UIColor, ask it for its CGColorRef, then expect that color to be around when the UIColor goes away.

The slightly [modified](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60414145/SampleEmission%202.zip) project, it works great on the simulator and device (iPhone 4).

[Note - really nice use of CAEmitter - pretty!!!]

Comment: Thank you so very much David :-) The reason I released CGColorRef, sometimes I couldn’t get the color change and so effects if I didn’t release it (I believed that was the reason) and I mostly won’t do the projects with ARC enabled. And thank you so much for your effort and appreciation :-)

Comment: You should switch to ARC. You only need to remember to keep a strong reference to objects, then release by setting the reference (ivar or property) to nil. When your class is released ARC then releases all your ivars/properties for you! I am using ARC one year now and could never to back to the old way!

Comment: I do want to try ARC. But, I couldn’t get out of the old way :-) Would surely try it out. Seems like ARC has more advantages!